# Is it okay to not run 'systemctl daemon-reload' after editing fstab?

Tags: configuration

So recently I have edited my /etc/fstab file for some purposes but forgot to run `systemctl daemon-reload` . But later on I executed after a reboot as I got reminded. It is completely okay or would it cause issues ?

Comment: `/etc/fstab` is only read once at boot and when using the `mount` or `umount` command. So don't worry, everything is okay.

Comment: Thank God ! Phew !! :)